# Is there any way to hide/override real IP while using proxy?

Tags: c#

I'm using the below code for web request via proxy. Is there any way to find the original ip while using the below code?

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("some url");

//Get random proxy address

IWebProxy proxy = new WebProxy("any ip address","any port");
request.Proxy = proxy;

WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

// Get the stream containing content returned by the server.  
Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();

StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
// Read the content.  
string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
// Clean up the streams and the response.  
reader.Close();
response.Close();
```

Comment: check if your proxy is sending the X-Forwarded-For header. If yes then yea its traceable. If not then nope it isnt